# Issue installing addon in ember cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am on 0.1.4 of ember-cli and tried installing an addon:
`ember install:addon ember-cli-simple-auth-cookie-store`
 but I got the error:
**The specified command install:addon is invalid, for available options see ember help.**

How can I go about installing this addon please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Installation Instructions for Ember CLI 0.1.4 and older: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth-cookie-store#installation